# correct number of instruction cycles and time? ASM PIC F18

Tags: assembly, pic

Can someone please just check if my answer is correct? :)

The question is:

**How long will it take for the following subroutine to execute if we use a 12 MHz crystal frequency on a F18 PIC?**

```
movlw .20
movwf n

again: 
decf n,f
bnz again
nop
nop
rlncf n,w
movwf PORTC
nop
return
```

**My answer is:**

22.66 ns which is about 23 ns.

We have 68 instruction cycles, right? And then one cycle will take .33333 ns??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 / 12000000 Hz * 4  = 0.33333 us and not 0.33333 ns.
So the right result is 22.6666 us or about 23 us.

Comment: ah yes of course, I got it wrong xD But should it be 22, 22.66, or 23 us?

Comment: 23 us is approximation of 22.6666 us, actuali the mistake is bigger than 1% or one instruction cycle so 22.6666 us is better.